# Only catch TypeError if the type/value was null

Tags: php, types, null

Specifically in class property setters, I would like to be able to handle empty values (null) differently from classically 'wrong' values, because an empty value might indicate something going wrong elsewhere in the code (as opposed to the user supplying incorrect data). Currently, I would do this:

```
/**
 * Checks and sets the user property.
 * 
 * @param   string|null  $user   The user to store
 * @return  void
 * 
 * @throws  InvalidRequestException
 * @access  public
 */
public function setUser(?string $user): void
{
    // Validate
    if (empty($user)) {
        throw new \InvalidRequestException('No user specified');
        // Or a custom exception
    }

    /// ... Code to handle $user variable ...
    
    // Store
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

Throwing an exception allows me to handle this scenario differently, however I feel like this makes the function signature somewhat misleading, as it implies that a null value is valid. I would much rather do this:

```
public function setUser(string $user): void
{
    /// ... Code to handle $user variable ...
    
    // Store
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

And then handle the null-scenario by catching that specific type of TypeError. Is that possible,  obviously without putting in more work than would be saved?

Comment: So you can set default value for $user param and than check it:  
 
public function setUser(string $user = ''): void
{
    if (empty($user)) {
        throw new \InvalidRequestException('No user specified');
    }

Comment: I think you're coming at this from the wrong angle. If the concern is that an incoming null is a symptom of a problem higher in the stack, then you should handle it there instead of here. Just disallow the null here, and throw an error on an empty string. But handle you actual concern closer to where it might originate.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me

```php
public function setUser(?string $user): void
{
    // Validate
    if (!is_string($user) || strlen($user) < 1) {
        // Exception
    }

    // Handler
    
    // Store
    $this->user = $user;
}
```